# ¿como se puede inmovilizar imagen en un scrollview?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, scroll

Tenemos un scrollview envolviendo un relative layout donde hay dos imageview una encima de otra,como se puede hacer que: al hacer scroll se mueva una imageview y la otra no?,gracias

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagenpregunta"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagen" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagen_no_mover"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"

                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagen2" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/pregunta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="algo"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton1"
                android:text="Observar"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
                android:textColor="#a80d0d"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hola Tutio. Has usado un búscador para la información que pides? Has llegado  a alguna conclusion o has hecho alguna prueba? Te ha dado errores? Por favor, mejora la pregunta siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Es importante agregues tu código y tu layout.

Comment: He buscado, pero no he encontrado nada , pongo el codigo para ver si me podeis ayudar,se me ocurre con un floatingbutton?